# do you have much milk? (problems in the formation of a negative form)

Tags: grammar

came across such a sentence in an English textbool:

```
do you have much milk? - no, we haven't.
```

whether the negative form is formed correctly?

and will it not be correct to write:

```
do you have much milk? - no, i haven't.
```

**why there "WE" instead of "I"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues here.

It is quite common to form the negative "We don't have much milk". But in the question or the positive you would use "a lot of", or "enough" (depending on what you mean)

> Do you have a lot of milk?

The answer would use the auxiliary verb "do"

> No, we don't.

Now for your question, the reason is that the speaker is replying as a member of a group of people.  The word "you" can be both singular, and mean "the one person I'm speaking to", or it can be plural and mean "The group of people I'm speaking to".

So when you reply, if you are just one person, you would say

> No, I don't.

But if you are speaking on behalf of a group of people, you say:

> No, we don't.

```
 o  Do you have           o No, we don't       O
/|\ enough milk?         /|\      o           /|\
 |                        |      /|\           |
/ \                      / \      |           / \
                                 / \
```

Someone working in a shop might say 'we don't have something' even if they are the only person working there at that time, because they are speaking on behalf of the shop organisation or company, which is considered to be a group of people.

Comment: Someone working in a shop might say 'we don't have _something_' even if they are the only person working there at that time, because they are speaking on behalf of the shop organisation or company, which is considered to be a group of people.

Comment: I've incorporated taht verbatim